# Output loop result in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops

Hi have this code and I don't know how to put the output result with every pixel.I think the output code are not well defined.

EDIT:

I'm going to try to explain the code:

```
% I have an image

    imagen1=imread('recor.tif');
    imagen2= double(imagen1);
    band1= imagen2(:,:,1);

% I preallocate the result (the image size is 64*89*6)
    yvan2= zeros(61,89,1);

% For every pixel of the image, I want to get one result (each one is different).
    for i = 1 : nfiles
        for j = 1 : nrows
            for i = 1:numel(band1)

% I'm doing this because I've to multiply the results of this interpolation with that result a2ldb1y= ldcm_1(:,1). This vector has a length of 2151x1 and I need to muliply the result of the interpolation for (101:267) position on the vector, this is the reason because I'm doing the interpolation since 101 to 267 (also because I don't have that values).

            interplan= interp1(van1,man2,t2,'spline');
             ma(96) = banda1a(i); % I said 96, because I want to do an interpollation 
            end                
            van1= [101 96 266]';
            mos1= ma(134);
            van2= [0 pos1 0];

            t= 101:267;
            t2= t';
            xi= 101:1:267;
            xi2=xi';
            interplan= interp1(van1,van2,t2,'spline');

% After this, I 'prepare' the vector.

            out=zeros(2151,1)
            out(101:267) = interplan;

% And then, I do all this operation (are important for the result) 

            a2ldb1y= ldcm_1(:,1); 
            a2ldsum_pesos1= sum(a2ldb1y);
            a2l7dout1_a= a2ldb1y.*out;
            a2l7dout1_b=  a2l7dout1_a./a2ldsum_pesos1;
            a2l7dout1_c= sum(a2l7dout1_b);

% And the result a2l7dout1_c I want it for every pixel (the results are different because every pixel has a different value...)
           **yvan2(:,:,1)= [a2l7dout1_c];**

        end 
    end
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I think your question is not well defined. What do you mean by _"put the output result with every pixel"_? And why do you have two loops using the same iteration variable `i`???

Comment: Because it's an image and I want to do this operation for all the pixels and the result of the interp1 and the next operations will be write as a output. a2l7dout1_c => This result is diferent for every pixel. I don't know if I'm explaining well...

Comment: So `a2l7dout1_c` is supposed to be a scalar? And what's the point of this line `ma(134) = banda1a(i)`? Why put it inside a loop?

Comment: Yes! ma(134) This it's because I need that value from the vector for the interpolation.

Comment: Please explain what this code is supposed to do. It is not at all clear. It is very difficult to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm shooting in the dark here, but I think you're looking for:

```
yvan2(i, j, 1)= a2l7dout1_c;
```

instead of:

```
yvan2(:,:,1)= [a2l7dout1_c];
```

and thus your output should be stored in the variable `yvan2` after the loops are done.

#### P.S

Some issues in your code:

1. Why do you have two loops using the same iteration variable `i`? Your calculations are probably incorrect since `i` is being modified by two `for` loops.
2. Why do you even need the second loop? Each iteration overruns the value of `ma(134)` set by the previous iteration. You can just replace the entire loop with:

   ```
   ma(134) = banda1a(numel(band1))
   ```
3. You shouldn't be using the names `i` and `j` for loop variables. They are already reserved for the imaginary unit (that is, `sqrt(-1)`), so MATLAB needs extra processing time for name resolution. You'd rather use other loop variable names instead, even `ii` and `jj`.

Comment: Thanks EitanT! ;) I'm trying it. I'm also going to change the code, I know it's hard to understand! Thanks for your advices!